# VBA: Global Variable Cleared after 'Workbook_Open' sub

Tags: vba, excel

I have set up an application level event class to monitor when new workbooks are created/ opened by following [CPearson's guide](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/appevent.aspx). This works fine in isolation. However, it is intended as part of add-in I'm writing where several other subs are also called in the 'Workbook_Open' sub, see below code:

```
Private XLApp As baseCXlEvents

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set XLApp = New baseCXlEvents
    test
    AddLocalReferences
    AddModules
    AddClassModules
    Debug.Print "testing"
End Sub
```

So the `XLApp` variable is called in the module scope as a `baseCXlEvents` class. I have added a `Class_Terminate` event to this class and this is triggered after the `Debug.print "testing"` is run, i.e. `XLApp` is terminated after the `Workbook_Open` sub has run. This does not happen when I quote out the subs `AddLocalReferences`, `AddModules`, and `AddClassModules`, which do exactly as their names would imply. The sub `test` only prints a messages in debug to test whether calling additional subs caused `XLApp` to be terminated.

My current 'hunch' is that adding references, modules, or class modules counts as "editing", causing it to be terminated, as explained in [this MS Support document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/141693). But, if so, why doesn't `XLApp` get terminated until the end of the sub? As opposed to as soon as `AddLocalReferences` is run.

Any suggestions why the class is terminated? I need it to 'stay alive' and also need to load additional modules and references for the addin upon workbook_open. If needed more details of this code can be provided.

I've decided to add my **baseCXlEvents class module's code**:

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub App_NewWorkbook(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    MsgBox "New Workbook: " & Wb.Name
End Sub

Private Sub App_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    MsgBox "Workbook opened: " & Wb.Name
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Debug.Print "Initializing baseCXlEvents instance.."
    Set App = Application
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Debug.Print "Terminating baseCXlEvents instance.."
End Sub
```

Comment: In the functions you do probably something which triggers the termination of the object ```XLApp```. But have you tried to move the ```Set XLApp = New baseCXlEvents``` to the very end of the ```Workbook_Open()``` procedure?

Comment: If it isn't used after that it might be the garbage collector? The only problem is the garbage collector for vba is not really documented so I am not sure on this, just a possibility.

Comment: @dee I have thought of that and actually did try moving the `Set` to the the back. This does not work. And wouldn't you expect to see the `Class_Terminate` trigger 'mid-sub' if this was the case?
@Evan It is not used afterward directly, but it should be 'on watch', monitoring events. Any suggestions on how to test this? [This article](http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/snippets/scope/garbage) suggests garbage is collected when all references are either gone or out of scope. Which is not the case here.

Comment: Should your declaration of `XLApp` include the hook for events... as in `Private WithEvents XLApp As baseCXlEvents`?

Comment: @PeterT : My baseCXlEvents class has `Private WithEvents App As Application` and 
`Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set App = Application
End Sub`
This should add the events hook for the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well then try to separate the `Workbook_Open` event handler stuff (where you add references etc.) from the creation of the instance of the class `baseCXlEvents` using `Auto_Open`.

`Workbook_Open` runs first, `Auto_Open` runs then.

*Note: `baseCXlEvents` Instancing must be set to Public.*

[image]

> ThisWorkbook class

```
Public XLApp As baseCXlEvents

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Test
    AddLocalReferences
    AddModules
    AddClassModules

End Sub
```

> Standard module

```
Sub Auto_Open()
   Set ThisWorkbook.XLApp = New baseCXlEvents
End Sub
```

Comment: this results in a compile error: "Private object modules cannot be used in public object modules as parameters or return types for public procedures, as public data members, or as fields of public user defined types"
I resolved this by placing `Private XLApp as BaseCXlEvents` in the standard module. Also, why do you declare `Public XLApp As **New** baseCXlEvents`?
PS: This DOES actually work. Caveat being that `Auto_Open` will not run if a workbook is opened programmatically ([source](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/auto_open-vs-workbook_open.953960/))

Comment: The code works, but you have to set the Instancing property of your class to Public (watch the Note :)).

Comment: Yes the Auto_Open has limits. And Workbook_Open won't fire when events are disabled.

Comment: Right, sorry about that. I wonder though, wouldn't it be preferable to keep the scope as 'tight' as possible? So declaring `Private XLApp as baseCXlEvents` in the normal module over `Public...` in `ThisWorkbook`? Also, why should it be `New baseCXlEvents`?

Comment: Yes that is right to have the variable XLApp private in module looks better. It is up to you. In that case the class instancing can remain private.

Comment: that is exactly what I chose to do. Thanks a lot for you help, had been puzzled by this for days. Sadly, still don't understand why the original won't work. But at least I have a working alternative.

Comment: It should be New baseCXlEvents because the instance of the class must be created. The baseCXlEvents is the name of your class which contains the Excel-App with events member, right? I am glad I could help :).

Comment: Right, but isn't the instance created when `Set XLApp = New baseCXlEvents` is run. So why declare it as a new instance as well? For some reason I recall it being 'bad practice' to declare variables with `New`, but I'm not sure about that and wouldn't know why if indeed it is..

Comment: Sorry my fault! Correct is to declare just without New. See the edited answer.

Comment: About ```New``` keyword in declaration read e.g. this aricle: [Don't Use Auto-Instancing Object Variables](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/declaringvariables.aspx). HTH